# Visual Studio Code exit button position

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does someone know why the Exit button is on the left where's the Menu Bar? Someone know how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: You could try running VS Code without extensions activated. If the issue still persists, I think you can consider opening an issue (maybe there's an issue already) at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues

Comment: Have you updated to v1.71.2 - I think it is fixed there.  Also see